# SAP Analysis for Excel: Create a new report via VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, sap-analysis-for-office

I'm currently experimenting with using the Excel plugin "SAP Analysis for Office" and VBA code.

With VBA, I'm able to change a existing opened report to my liking.

However, now I want to create a completely new report using VBA.

Sadly I do not know how to start with this.
Is it possible to do the following steps via VBA and if yes, how would I be able to implement it?:

- Open up the Analysis for Excel plugin in a plain empty Excel file
- Open up a specific report as I would do it manually (Insert data source --> define data source for analysis --> login --> select the SAP report)

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.